# Printing an object - iPhone app

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, nsstring, nsmutablearray

I'm trying to print out an object called Contact (an extension of NSObject I wrote).

When my app first launches, I have the following code:

```
NSMutableArray *arr = [UserData getGroupNames];
    NSLog(@"group names are %@",arr);
    for(int i = 0; i < [arr count]; i++) {
        NSString *name = [arr objectAtIndex:i];
        NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        NSData *data = [defaults objectForKey:name];
        NSArray *a = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
        NSLog(@"name = %@",name);
        NSLog(@"array count is %i",[a count]);
        for(int i = 0; i < [a count]; i++) {
            NSLog(@"on index %i",i);
            Contact *c = [a objectAtIndex:i];
            NSLog(@"got contact");
            if(c == nil)
                NSLog(@"it's nil!");    
            NSLog(@"contact first name = %@",[c getFirst]);
            NSLog(@"got contact %@",c);
```

So, I get my array called "a" and try and print it out. Well, that doesn't work. The program just sits there and doesn't do anything. It doesn't error out or exit out, it literally just stops doing anything.

So I print the count, and that turns out to be 1. So clearly there is something in the array. So then, I grab the first Contact from the array, and my console prints "got contact" fine.

Then, I test to see if that contact is nil. Well, it's not.

Then, I try to print the contact. And my program stops running. In the console I just see "(gdb)" and nothing prints, and nothing continues to run. The program just sits.

What is going on? I am just printing a Contact (which, by the way, has a description method set up which only prints out an NSString).

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "print"? Do you want to display on the screen, console, or via AirPrint?

Comment: it is evident in my code. I'm trying to do an NSLog on that object "c"

Comment: @reising1 What happens when you take out `NSLog(@"contact first name = %@",[c getFirst]);`? You don't mention it being printed.

Comment: yeah, that doesn't get printed either. and without it, "c" doesn't print on its own. ugh.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6698088/nsuserdefaults-nscoder-custom-class-iphone-app-question

Comment: It's evident on your code but not on your title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd bet `c` is a bad object.  Try `NSStringFromClass([c class])`, but also try stepping in the debugger and seeing how it goes.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6698088/nsuserdefaults-nscoder-custom-class-iphone-app-question

Comment: ahh, hah, so `c` *was* bad, it was referencing freed objects